# How to push a view with custom left pane in SplitViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a splitview controller, and I when a cell is selected in the detail view, I want to push a view that replaces both the left and right panes.

The code below replaces only the right pane with a custom view.

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SecondViewController class])
    bundle:nil];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

I would like to load in the left pane another table.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to replace the splitviewcontroller view. What you are doing there is pushing onto whatever navigationcontroller you are on which I assume is your details or your navigation side of the split view controller.

Something like this will brute force it but you'd have to change it for what you need more:

AppDelegate *myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[myDelegate.splitViewController.view addSubView secondView.view];

Or maybe try replacing the app delegate rootViewcontroller

myDelegate.window.rootViewController = secondView;

This is all assuming you have the correct properties but you will have to think of a solution that doesn't just push a view controller onto whatever self is in your above code snippet. I hope that helps